# Clarification on marginal, posterior and likelihood distributions?

Tags: posterior, likelihood, marginal-distribution

I would like to clarify a basic question about how to use the concepts of marginal, conditional, and likelihood distributions.

When we observe data from phenomena $x$. We are looking at realizations from the *marginal* distribution $f(x)$?

When we want to say something about a parameter $\theta$ governing that phenomena, we are usually interested in its *posterior* distribution $f(\theta| x)$?

And in order to investigate that conditional distribution we make use of prior information and the hypothesized relationship between $\theta$ and the data $x$. We call this later relationship the *likelihood* distribution $f(x|\theta)$?

Is this the write terminology? If not I would appreciate clarifications where needed.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by talking about a **marginal distribution**.  Whenever we have a joint probability distribution $P(X, Y)$, if we draw samples from this distribution and only look at $X$ we have essentially samples from the marginal distribution $P(X)$.  The marginal distribution removes $Y$ from the picture by *summing* or *integrating* $P(X,Y)$ over all possible values that $Y$ can take.

$$
P(X=x) = \int P(X=x, Y=y) dy
$$

In your examples you were mainly dealing with Bayesian Perimetric Models.  Let's consider the following model:

$$
\mu \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1),
$$

$$
X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, 1).
$$

Let's refer to $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ as $X$.  In this problem we have observed $X$ and we want to understand $\mu$.  With our model, if we knew $\mu$ calculating the probability of each $X_i$ would be easy.  So we can easily evaluate the **conditional** probability $P(X_i | \mu)$.  Because of the importance of this distribution in maximum likelihood estimation this is referred to as the **likelihood distribution**.

As you said in your question we are ultimately interested in $P(\mu | X)$.  This is another **conditional distribution** that we refer to as the **posterior distribution** ("post" or after we've seen data).  **Bayes' Theorem** tells us how to relate the Likelihood distribution and the Posterior Distribution.  However, in this formulation two more factors appear including the (frequentists call it subjective and this is a marginal but don't think about it too hard) **prior distribution** $P(\mu)$ and the (often horrible to calculate) marginal distribution $P(X)$.